# Overriding PriceHelper in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to override `PriceHelper` class by adding `getOriginalPrice` function but since the service not registered, on `service.yml`, I put:

```
services:
    AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper\:
        class: AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper
        arguments:
            - "@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price"
        tags:
            - { name: templating.helper, event: sylius.templating.helper.price, method: getOriginalPrice, alias: sylius_calculate_original_price }
```

On twig, I added:

```
{%- macro calculateOriginalPrice(variant) -%}
  {% from _self import convertAndFormat %}
  {{- convertAndFormat(variant|sylius_calculate_original_price({'channel': sylius.channel})) }}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

and replaced:

```
{{ money.calculatePrice(product|sylius_resolve_variant) }}
```

to

```
{{ money.calculateOriginalPrice(product|sylius_resolve_variant) }}
```

Error:

```
Unknown "sylius_calculate_original_price" filter. Did you mean 
"sylius_calculate_price"?
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
The services.yml is actually fine. Just need to add below in config.yml:

```
twig:
    globals:
        sylius_calculate_original_price: "@app.templating.helper.price"
```

and in twig:

```
{{ sylius_calculate_original_price.getOriginalPrice(variant,{'channel': sylius.channel}) }}
```

services.yml can be shorten to:

```
app.templating.helper.price:
    decorates: sylius.templating.helper.price
    class: AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper
    arguments:
        - "@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price"
```

Answer (score 0):

The PriceHelper service is configured in this file: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/f7d42d2ce64288407372775e0ed421debcd50cd3/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services/templating.xml

But instead of replacing the service like you did, you should decorate it. Extend the PriceHelper class with a new class and add the functionality that you need, then add configuration for your new service like described in the following link, to decorate the PriceHelper service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

In your specific case, you have to use this configuration:

```
AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper:
    decorates: '@sylius.templating.helper.price'
    arguments:
        $productVariantPriceCalculator: '@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price'
```

Comment: I updated as below:
`services:
        AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper\:
            decorates: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\PriceHelper
            class: AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper
            arguments:
                - "@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price"
            tags:
                - { name: templating.helper, event: sylius.templating.helper.price, 
method: getOriginalPrice, alias: sylius_calculate_original_price }`



and error shows:
`You have requested a non-existent service "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\PriceHelper".`

Comment: Where does it throw that error? Please post the whole stack trace or error message context, if possible.

Comment: error shows when the page call the calculateOriginalPrice function.

full log:
`(1/1) ServiceNotFoundException
You have requested a non-existent service "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\PriceHelper".

in ContainerBuilder.php line 1043
at ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('Sylius\\Bundle\\CoreBundle\\Templating\\Helper\\PriceHelper')
in DecoratorServicePass.php line 55
at DecoratorServicePass->process(object(ContainerBuilder))
in Compiler.php line 141
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder))
in ContainerBuilder.php line 778
at ContainerBuilder->compile()`

Comment: if I change the decorates to:
`decorates: sylius.templating.helper.price`
and removed the arguments, below error throw instead:

`Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper\": argument "$productVariantPriceCalculator" of method "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\PriceHelper::__construct()" references interface "Sylius\Component\Core\Calculator\ProductVariantPriceCalculatorInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "sylius.calculator.product_variant_price" service.`

Comment: Try the following service configuration:
    `AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper:
        decorates: sylius.templating.helper.price
        arguments:
            $productVariantPriceCalculator: '@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price'`

Comment: Updated to:
    `AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper\:
        decorates: sylius.templating.helper.price
        class: AppBundle\Helper\PriceHelper
        arguments:
            $productVariantPriceCalculator: '@sylius.calculator.product_variant_price'
        tags:
            - { name: templating.helper, event: sylius.templating.helper.price, method: getOriginalPrice, alias: sylius_calculate_original_price }
`
Err:
`Unknown "sylius_calculate_original_price" filter. Did you mean "sylius_calculate_price"?`

Comment: I tested by changing calculateOriginalPrice to calculatePrice to override existing function and it would work. 

So, the issue should be: "how to register new function to be used in Twig"